# RabbitMQ RPC multiple senders one receiver

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc

Hi i'm really new to RabbitMQ. I want implement the RPC pattern but with multiple clients and one server. Can anyone recommend a responsive way of implementing this. I'm a bit concerned the code I have implementing one client and one server will introduce blocking issues, ideally I'd like the client to get a response fairly quickly.

Comment: May I ask what business problem do you need to solve?

Answer (score 1):

First just to get terminology straight:

- in RMQ context, RMQ is a broker (server) whose clients are producers and consumers.
- in RPC context (and in example on [the tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html)) we have a RPC client(s) and a RPC server(s). So when we "map"this to RMQ context, we say that RPC client is actually both RMQ producer and RMQ consumer (because it sends the request and receives a reply) and that RPC server is both RMQ consumer and RMQ producer (because it waits for requests and then sends a reply)

Now, if you implement it the same way that's done in the tutorial (aforementioned link), you won't have any problems. You should simply start more RPC servers, so that more requests may be handled in parallel.

Comment: OK to answer Alexy's question. The business problem is we have a website that needs to communicate to a rather old accounting software who's API is more geared towards desktop apps having long running connections over the network. The vendor doesn't support and has hinted at threading issues in our scenario. So our next approach is to to have the web app send messages to RabbitMQ and have a console app permanantly connected to the accounting app which listens to the queue and if the process isn't too long be able to notify the web app user that the transaction has been processed/queued

Comment: So to come back to cantSleep from the tutorial (I have used a different one). From a performance/sensible architecture approach. Is it OK for the RPC client to create a temporary queue for the web app on a per call basis and route back to that. I'm not by my computer at the moment so I can't run though the tutorial. But from looking at it it creates one queue. Just a bit concerned that one queue could produce a bottleneck. I've seen some examples which create temporory queue which last the duration of the transaction. Is that a more a scalable direction.